# Is there a way to see System Information before first user is added?

Tags: macos, system-information, build-version

I have a Mac that someone asks me to help them sell.  They already wiped the hard drive and put a fresh installation of macOS on it. Upon boot, it's at the "Welcome" setup with no users intialized yet.

Is there an easy way to see the System Information and version of macOS currently installed on this machine without creating a new user? I'd like to leave this machine in a clean state without having to re-wipe the hard drive with a new installation.

Comment: Do you have another Mac? Want to boot in target disk mode?

Comment: @bmike Yes, but I'd prefer an answer assuming no other Mac around. Thanks!

Answer (score 42, accepted):

The following assumes that the **Recovery HD** has the same version of **macOS** installed on the **Macintosh HD** for the accuracy of OS version information.

If you boot the Mac to **Recovery Mode**, you can access **System Information** from **Terminal** using the following *command*, e.g.:

```
/Volumes/Macintosh\ HD/usr/sbin/system_profiler
```

You might what to minimize the *output* and use and of the following *options*:

- **-listDataTypes**  - Lists the available datatypes.
- **-detailLevel** *level* - Specifies the level of detail for the report:

  - *mini* - Report with no personal information.
  - *basic* - Basic hardware and network information.
  - *full*  - All available information.

To get just a **Hardware:** report, use:

- **SPHardwareDataType**

Example:

```
/Volumes/Macintosh\ HD/usr/sbin/system_profiler SPHardwareDataType
```

On my system the *outout* of the above *command* was:

```
Hardware:

    Hardware Overview:

      Model Name: MacBook Pro
      Model Identifier: MacBookPro10,1
      Processor Name: Intel Core i7
      Processor Speed: 2.8 GHz
      Number of Processors: 1
      Total Number of Cores: 4
      L2 Cache (per Core): 256 KB
      L3 Cache: 8 MB
      Memory: 16 GB
      Boot ROM Version: MBP101.00EE.B12
      SMC Version (system): 2.3f36
      Serial Number (system): <Information omitted for security reasons.>
      Hardware UUID: <Information omitted for security reasons.>
```

---

**Notes:**

To boot to the Recovery HD, press <kbd>Command</kbd><kbd>R</kbd> when booting the Mac. See also [About macOS Recovery](https://support.apple.com/HT201314)

Also, have a look at the manual page for [`system_profiler`](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man8/system_profiler.8.html)

If you want to just get information for some of the `-listDataTypes` listed, you can add each on the *command line*, e.g.:

```
/Volumes/Macintosh\ HD/usr/sbin/system_profiler SPHardwareDataType SPSoftwareDataType
```

---

The `system_profiler` *command* can be run directly from [**single-user mode**](https://support.apple.com/HT201573), by pressing <kbd>Command</kbd><kbd>S</kbd> when booting the Mac, without having to provide the *fully qualified pathname*, however depending on how much information you want from `system_profiler`, you may need to *pipe* the *output* to `more` to `less`, etc., as scrolling in **single-user mode** is not as easy as from **Terminal** when booted to the **Recovery HD**.

That said, if all you want is the basic output shown under **Hardware:** and **Software:** from using the `system_profiler` *command*, then use the following *command* in **single-user mode**:

```
system_profiler SPHardwareDataType SPSoftwareDataType
```

Note that the software info from single-user mode is that which is install on the Macintosh HD, unlike from the Recovery HD it's that of the OS X Base System and while it should be the same, it may not. The hardware info is accurate in either case.

Comment: **Macintosh\ HD** is not always right, so my tip for all, try first **cd /Volumes** here you get all volumes (in my case it was disks02) then you can use the right volume instead of **Macintosh HD**, the remaining path is absolutely correct.

Comment: On Catalina + Big Sur recovery mode I was getting this error: `dyld: Library not loaded: /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/SPSupport.framework/Versions/A/SPSupport`. The fix was to first `chroot /Volumes/Macintosh\ HD zsh`. After that, `/usr/sbin/system_profiler` works as expected.

Comment: @NatePinchot when trying to chroot on an M1 mac, I get the error: "killed: 9". Any ideas why?

Answer (score 38):

In my case `system_profiler` would not load (Abort trap: 6), and `sw_vers`  only shows the OS version. I needed the processor, memory and disk details.

Boot into Recovery Mode, holding <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> at boot. Then go into **Utilities > Terminal**

**Processor**

```
$ sysctl -n machdep.cpu.brand_string
Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-5257U CPU @ 2.70GHz
```

**Memory**

```
$ sysctl -n hw.memsize
17179869184
```

16 GB RAM = `17179869184 / 1024 / 1024 / 1024`

**Disk Space**

```
$ diskutil list
/dev/disk1 (internal):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                         500.3 GB   disk0
   1:                        EFI EFI                     314.6 MB   disk0s1
   2:                 Apple_APFS Container disk1         500.0 GB   disk0s2
```

500 GB

**Battery**

```
$ ioreg -rc AppleSmartBattery | grep -E '(CycleCount|Capacity)" ='
  "DesignCapacity" = 4563
  "AppleRawMaxCapacity" = 4092
  "CycleCount" = 19
```

89.7% = 4092 / 4563 * 100

Comment: Thanks! This was the only thing that worked on the newer M1 macs

Comment: `system_profiler` uses the `/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/SPSupport.framework` which is not on the install media. However copying this framework on to external media and accessing it there doesn't solve the problem. `system_profiler` will run but return no data. There must be more resources it needs available.

Comment: I didn't have `system_profiler` on my mac mini, and this worked perfectly.

Answer (score 6):

Easy - boot to single-user mode and then shut down.

1. Hold S key while booting (if you miss when the chime starts and the setup assistant runs - quit and shut down).
2. When the black screen shows white text - wait for it to stop and type `sw_vers`.
3. Once you’ve recorded the information, type `halt`.

You can use `sw_vers` in any mode. Its output looks like this:

```
$ sw_vers 
ProductName:    Mac OS X
ProductVersion: 10.13.1
BuildVersion:   17B1003
```

Comment: Could you give an indication of what it shows if you do?

Comment: @Maarten Bodewes, It will output 3 lines, e.g.: `ProductName: Mac OS X`, `Product Version: 10.13.1` and `BuildVersion: 17B1003`

Answer (score 4):

1. Enter recovery mode:

   - Intel: by pressing <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> when powering on
   - M1: just press the "power on" button and keep it pressed until you see recovery options, then choose "Options"
2. Open `Utilities` > `Terminal`
3. Type following:

   ```
   $ sysctl hw.physicalcpu hw.logicalcpu machdep.cpu.brand_string hw.memsize
   $ diskutil info disk0
   ```

Where:

- `hw.physicalcpu` is number of cores
- `hw.logicalcpu` is number of threads
- `machdep.cpu.brand_string` is CPU model info
- `hw.memsize` is RAM size in bytes, just divide it by 1024^3
- `Device / Media Name` is drive hardware name (device name)
- `Disk Size` actual physical disk size
- `Protocol` will be `PCI-Express` even for NVME disks, don't worry

**Based on @user3439894 and @nate-pinchot answers, you can also try:**

```
$ chroot /Volumes/Macintosh\ HD bash
$ system_profiler SPHardwareDataType SPSoftwareDataType SPPowerDataType
```

there will be more info, like:

- `Model Identifier`
- `Serial Number`
- `System Version`
- `Cycle Count`

In case if you using FileVault this way requires you to unlock startup disk first: After entering Recovery, login into admin user, then press  > `Startup disk` > Choose `Macintosh HD` > `Remove protection` > Type your password > Click "Startup drive" > Quit

Answer (score 2):

The best way to do this and to access everything you would otherwise see in **System Information** is to boot into **single-user mode** by holding Command + S while booting up. Once you see the white-on-black text, you'll then want to then input:

`system_profiler -listDataTypes`

This will give you a list of all the different 'DataTypes' or more simply what type of information you can choose to see, very similar to how it's displayed in the **System Information** app. If, for example, you want to then see battery cycle information, you could then enter:

`system_profiler SPPowerDataType`

It will then print the Battery Information along with Cycle Count to the screen.

Replacing `SPPowerDataType` in that previous statement with any of the other listed DataTypes will also return relevant information.

Answer (score 0):

The following is the easiest way I've found to do this:

First boot to the welcome screen, then open the apple menu at the top left (it is hidden until you move the mouse there).
Once it is open hold down the option key and "About This Mac" will change to "System Information" which will open the normal system profiler.

Strangely even though "About This Mac" is there you cannot open it.

Answer (score 0):

I just used this, but found one quirk: it does require that their *be* an OS installed, and doesn't work on Macs that *only* have a Recovery partition. However, `system_profiler` does exist on the Recovery partition. Follow the steps above, but instead use:

```
/Volumes/"OS X Base System"/usr/sbin/system_profiler SPHardwareDataType
```

or

```
 /Volumes/"macOS Base System"/usr/sbin/system_profiler SPHardwareDataType
```

whichever the partition is named, and it works like a charm!